# iPhone URL Request: Add value to HTTP header field

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add a value to the header for a URL request.

Something like this works just fine:

```
[urlRequest addValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
```

But this doesn't even show up in the header:

```
NSString *authString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                          [defaults objectForKey:@"auth"]];
[urlRequest addValue:authString forHTTPHeaderField:@"iphoneID"];
```

I'm completely stumped. The auth string is around 90 characters long. Is this a problem?

*Edit:*
Here's the code I'm trying:

```
NSString *authString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[defaults objectForKey:@"auth"]]; 
[urlRequest addValue:authString forHTTPHeaderField:@"iphoneid"]; 
[urlRequest addValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
```

I can see the Accept-Encoding header being sent through Wireshark, but iphoneid is nowhere to be found. It's just a string, 80-90 characters long.

*Another Update:*
So it seems that the problem isn't the field "iphoneid" but rather the authString I'm trying to pass into it. Other strings that I just create with the @"something" work fine, but the auth string that I pull from NSUserDefaults doesn't appear.

Suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: Did you verified the value of [defaults objectForKey:@"auth"] with an NSLog ? Did you checked the request to see which headers are sent (you can use HTTPScoop) ?

There is a limit for HTTP headers, but 90 is not a problem.

Comment: Yeah. It prints out fine with a NSLog and I've checked the header with both HTTPScoop & Wireshark.

Comment: So if you can see the header in HTTPScoop, you can conclute it has been sent. You should probably look for a problem on your webserver instead.

Comment: I think I misspoke.

The header is /not/ going through. The gzip header shows up just fine, but the auth header seems to not be added to the request. This is the problem I'm having.

Comment: We're going to need to see some more code then! Does it fail in the simulator, or on the device? Or both? What if you try some other header values or fields?

Comment: Added some code for review. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you need to run the auth string through the NSString method stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding before putting in the header?

Comment: Why did you accept spam as the answer? Very odd...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The true problem.

The string I was pulling from NSUserDefaults already had a line ending. When set as a header, another `\r\n` is appended, which apparently isn't valid. Thus, the header wouldn't appear in any outgoing packets.

### The fix:

Use this to trim off the characters before setting as a header value.

`[yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];`

Answer (score 2):

Testing checklist:

- Verify that you actually have a NSMutableURLRequest (and not a NSURLRequest) at this point. In particular, check your logs for an exception due to "unrecognized selector."
- Verify that urlRequest is not nil.
- Switch to setValue:forHTTPHeaderField: rather than addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:.
- Swap the forHTTPHeaderField: value to @"Accept-Encoding" to see if the field is the problem
- Swap @"gzip" for auth to see if the value is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need Charles web proxy, to see what header values are really outbound and inbound.  Then you can see if the problem is really in your code or some magic on the server discarding things.

There's a free trial, and after you install it if you hit record any traffic the simulator sends will go through the proxy.  Very nice.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: I've been using Wireshark that does total packet capture over network interfaces and let's me follow a TCP stream. Is there something unique about Charles?

Comment: Just easier to use and view results from in different ways.

If you are happy with Wireshark that is fine, as long as you can see the data you need.

Comment: Wow! Charles is VERY easy to work with. Thanks@Kendall

Comment: Just to add a bit more to this, Wireshark is also an X11 app so you have to install QuartzX to use it...