# Problem with NSString and NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am having issues with adding a header to NSMutableURlRequest, the problem is that when I add the header below "Authorization" it does not show up. However if I replace my instance variable "auth" below with a static string exp (@"asdadsadsadga") it the "Authorization" header will show up. I am pretty lost at this point.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default"];
NSMutableURLRequest *profileRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSLog(auth); //prints correctly
NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin Auth=%@", auth];
[profileRequest addValue:authString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSDictionary *allheaders = [profileRequest allHTTPHeaderFields];

for (id key in allheaders)
{
  //Nothing prints
  NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [allheaders objectForKey:key]);
}

NSLog(auth); //Prints correctly
```

Comment: This sounds like the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791760, which was also an auth token (but unfortunately there was no follow-up to the question there). Maybe it's a specific character that's causing it to fail; when you tried a string literal, was it the same content as your auth variable? If not, I'd try that, and if it fails start removing characters until it works.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried the same exact token as a literal. Also, authString is created correctly, I can run NSLog(@"%@", authString) and get the correct output. It really has me stumped.

Comment: Can you post the exact output of running this code please.

Answer (score 1):

First, swap out NSLog(auth) with NSLog(@"%@", auth). The former is dangerous, and may expose some of what's going on here. You should also try adding early on:

```
auth = @"asdasdasdad";
```

You should also try just dumping allheaders directly:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [profileRequest allHTTPHeaderFields];
```

This may shed some light. I suspect that the problem is in your auth variable, possibly related to memory management, not in NSMutableURLRequest.

Comment: While the NSLog statement is potentially crashy/incorrect, the creation of authString is safe, so it's hard to see how that could be relevant.

It also can't be a memory management issue, since according to the sample code auth is still valid at the end of the chunk of code that doesn't work.

Comment: Your problem isn't reproducible, so the actual content of "auth" is extremely relevant.

Comment: Auctually, I seem to have reproduced it. It must be with how we are getting the string. I am using some code I found to base64Encode the username/password, and clearly it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using to generate your base64Encoded string is broken.

Try using the method outlined at the bottom of the page: 
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html